Cannot access old YouTube channel associated with Google brand account
I have an old YouTube channel ( https://www.youtube.com/@meditatewithme50 ), created back in 2018, which is associated with a Google brand account that I'm the primary owner of.  My Google account is clearly shown as "Primary Owner" of that brand account.  However, when I'm logged into YouTube with that Google account, I'm unable to access that channel.  How do I access my YouTube channel again?
